# Convert multi-dimensional array to multi-dimensional dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How do I convert a multi-dimensional array of int into a multi-dimensional dictionary using Lambda?

For example I would like to convert Test1 (int[2,3]) into Test 3 (Dictionary<(int,int),int>)

```
    int[,] Test1 = new int[2, 3];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Test1[i, j] = k++;
        }
    }
```

I can easily convert it into dictionary using the traditional way with the "for - next" loop but when I tried using lambda:

```
Dictionary<(int,int),int>Test3 = Enumerable.Range(0, Test1.Length)
    .ToDictionary((int i ,int j )=>new { z =Test1[i, j] });
```

I got the syntax error below:

```
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

How do I specify the type arguments explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't easily use Linq to loop through "rows" of a 2-D array, since the iterator for a square array just loops through the elements. You'll need to use an old-fashion `for` loop:

```
var Test3 = new Dictionary<(int,int),int>();

for (int i = 0; i < Test1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Test3[(Test1[i, 0], Test1[i, 1])] =  Test1[i, 2];
}
```

This assumes that the pairs in the first two "columns" are unique, otherwise the last one would "win".

You *could* use Linq to enumerate through the rows by usinng `Range` over one axis as you tried to do:

```
Dictionary<(int,int),int>Test3 = Enumerable
    .Range(0, Test1.GetLength(0))
    .ToDictionary(i => (Test1[i, 0], Test1[i, 1]), i => Test1[i, 2]);
```

Note that the lambdas in `ToDictionary` define the key and value, respectively.

but the `for` loop is cleaner and easier to understand in my opinion.

Comment: @D Stanley: Thanks Stanley! Good to know... I thought I had issue with understanding lambda leading to the syntax error...